# Play compilation error: cannot access Function0

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0

I just created a new Play project in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 using wizard as described here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/getting-started-with-play-2-x.html#create_project

IntelliJ doesn't reports any errors and rebuild also succeeds without errors. Even "sbt run" starts server without problems. But when I open http://localhost:9000 in browser, I see:

```
[info] Compiling 7 Scala sources and 1 Java source to C:\vyvoj\play5\target\scala-2.11\classes...
[error] C:\vyvoj\play5\target\scala-2.11\routes\main\controllers\routes.java:12: error: cannot access Function0
[error]   public static final controllers.ReverseAssets Assets = new controllers.ReverseAssets(RoutesPrefix.byNamePrefix());
[error]                                                          ^
[error]   class file for scala.Function0 not found
[error] 1 error
[error] (compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] application -
```

Maybe java compiler doesn't see scala libraries, but why?

Thanks,
Pavel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by updating sbt.version to 0.13.13 in project/build.properties (it was 0.13.5).